# creating a fast case statement (assembly)

Tags: delphi

I have a project that has intensive use of the case statement with many procedures coming off it.  I know you can place case statements in a two tear arrangement divide in blocks of 10 and a second case statement to separate individual procedures.  But I have a better idea if I can pull it off.
I want to call it assembly case

```
Prolist: array [1..500] of Pointer =
          (@Procedure1, @Procedure2, @Procedure3, @Procedure4, @Procedure5);


Procedure ASMCase(Prolist: array of Pointer; No: Word; Var InRange: Boolean);
var Count : DWord;
    PTR: Pointer;
    Pro : Procedure;
begin
  Count := No * 4;
  InRange := boolean(Count <= SizeOf(Prolist));
  If not InRange then Exit;
  PTR := Pointer(DWord(@Prolist[1]) + Count);
  If PTR <> nil then Pro := @PTR else Exit;
  Pro;  /run procedure
end;​
```

The point is I'm creating a direct jump to the procedure.
In my case procedures can have an identical header and global data can be accessed for any odd information.  Writing it in assembly would be faster I think but what I'm not sure on is running the procedures. Please do not ask why am I doing this as I have 500 procedures with many calls on the case statement and time is of essence with a fast processor.

Comment: This is one of the worst cases of *premature optimization* I've ever seen. There is zero probability that your (poorly implemented) implementation of `case` is going to be any faster than that generated by the compiler. What benchmark have you used that is showing you that the compiler-generated `case` is a bottleneck in your code? *I have a project that has no problem, but I think I can improve it by some silly attempt at improving code that is not an issue (and in the process can make the code highly more convoluted, complicated, and harder to maintain).* is **always** a bad idea.

Comment: 500 if .. then statements take too much processor time final. this is 50 times faster in pratice easily. What I'm interested in is how to use Delphi code to give me flexibility to access procedures or methods.

Comment: You don't need 500 `if..then` statements. If you think you do, you're doing something horribly wrong. Doing something equally wrong to attempt to fix it isn't an improvement. Google *XY problem*. You're trying to add a horrible fix to the problem instead of solving the actual problem. Perhaps instead of asking how to write the assembly code, you should be asking how to solve the problem that leads you to thinking you need to do so.Instead of trying to treat the symptoms, cure the illness that's causing them.

Comment: You already have this code that directly accesses the array. Why do you think it will be an improvement to access the array indirectly through a case statement? Why don't you write your case statement in Delphi first, and then convert it to assembler afterward. The compiler will actually do the conversion for you, so you don't have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

It's expensive to pass that array by value. Pass it by const.

I can't see the point of the `InRange` flag and test. Don't pass out of range indices. And if you have to test, do it right. Don't use `SizeOf` which measures byte size. Use `high` or perhaps `Length`, if you have to. Which I doubt.

The pointer assignment test (`PTR <> nil`) is bogus. That condition always evaluates true. And the array indexing is very weird. What's wrong with `[]`?

On top of that, your array is 1-based (usually a bad choice) but open arrays are always 0-based. Likely that's going to trip you up.

In short, I'd throw away all of that code. It's both wrong and needless. I'd just write it like this:

```
ProList[No]();
```

In order for this to compile your array would need to be defined as an array of procedural type rather than array of `Pointer`. Adding some type safety would be a good move.

It's pretty hard to see asm making much difference here. The compiler is going to emit optimal code.

If you are concerned with out of bound access, enable range checking in debug mode. Disable it for release if performance is paramount.

Bear in mind that global data structures don't tend to scale well as you add complexity. Most experienced programmers go to some length to avoid global state. Are you sure that global state is the right choice for you?

If you do need to improve performance, first identify opportunity for improvement. Reading from an array and calling a function are not likely candidates. Look at the procedures that you call. The bottlenecks are surely there.

One final point. Try to forget that you ever learn to use `@` with function pointers. Doing so yields an untyped pointer, of type `Pointer` that can be assigned to any pointer type. And thus you completely abandon type checking. Your procedure could have the wrong signature altogether and the compiler is not able to tell you. Declare your array of procedures with a type safe procedure type.

Comment: InRange is to point out an error, or equivalent to an else statement in the case statement. That's what I need for my project.

Comment: SizeOf is a good tool that's found all though out Delphi low level code that some people need to use some time, as when in dealt it removes errors that you can be removed latter with testing.

Comment: Its help with how to use pointers around methods I lack experience to get the most out of my code.

Comment: I need to get past type checking with pointers. Its that the complier understands it and executes the procedure correctly that interests me. I just remembered installing methods from *.dll's that heavily used pointers to name test and access methods like this. I'm going to look for some code because I'm not going to get answers from hear.

Comment: Prolist is a const if you would look

Comment: Lex, by your own admission, you lack experience. David does not. You don't *need* to avoid type checking. You're avoiding it now because you previously wrote bad code, and in an attempt to make it compile, you started abandoning safeties. The solution is to go back and write good code instead. If you need to avoid type checking with the code you've shown here, then you're already doing something wrong and you'll need to backtrack further. The solution is *not* to plow ahead adding even more things you don't understand.

Comment: I kinda found my answer in web site :- http://jkgdelphi001.blogspot.co.nz/2014/06/procedural-type-method-pointer-in-delphi.html  but I wish I could have talked with more constructive people on this forum that new their subject to comment.

Comment: @LexDean The main reason why you didn't get "satisfying" answer here is becouse in your question you were asking on how to make faster case statment and not how to pass method pointer as parameter which is what in the end seems you were looking for. Unfortunately your question didn't provide us with enough information to know what you realy wish. So don't be to disapointed on Stack Owerflow community becouse of this.

Comment: @Lex, the blog you linked is a partial copy/paste of [`documentation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Procedural_Types). The blogger looks like one of those *always professional code lovers*, so I would kindly ask you to remove your spammy comment with that link. Thanks! To your problem, if you didn't do any profiling, don't randomly choose a language construct to blame.

Comment: What you perhaps have misunderstood is that your code has around 8 mistakes as I count them. I know what `SizeOf` does. You it seems do not. You used it wrongly. As for ProList being a constand, the original array is I understand that. The open array parameter is not. In my answer you can find the optimal code.

Comment: Re: @ operator - you can enable type-safe @ pointers with {$T+} (I always do). In the few cases where you need unsafe @ pointers, just cast it explicitly to POINTER at that point in your source... That way you (and anyone else) can see that you explicitly want to turn off type checking at those specific points...

Comment: @HeartWare for a procedure though `@` always returns `Pointer`.

Comment: @HEARTWARE Of course, typed address on is always a good idea and it beggars belief that this is not the default.

Comment: An array of procedures is what I'm doing because it works so much faster for this task. I have tested it.